# Taking Ownership of AD Computer Objects

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am needing a way to change the owner of a computer object in Active Directory before joining the computer to the domain. Basically, what I would like to do, is to connect to Active Directory from a computer that is not joined to the domain using the credentials of a technician (which they are prompted for in the script), then change the owner of the current hostname's computer object to the technician's AD user account.

```
# Prompt for credentials
$credential = Get-Credential -Message "Enter your Active Directory credentials"

# Specify the computer object's name
$computer = hostname

# Specify the new owner's username
$newOwner = $credential.UserName

try {
    # Import the Active Directory module
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory

    # Get the computer object
    $computerObject = Get-ADComputer -Identity $computer -Server "contoso.com" -Credential $credential

    if ($computerObject -eq $null) 
    {
        Write-Host "Computer object not found in Active Directory. Please verify the computer name: $computer"
        exit
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Computer object found in Active Directory for $computer"
    }

    # Get the new owner's object
    $newOwnerObject = Get-ADUser -Identity $newOwner -Server "contoso.com" -Credential $credential

    if ($newOwnerObject -eq $null) 
    {
        Write-Host "New owner not found in Active Directory. Please verify the username: $newOwner"
        exit
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "New owner, $newOwner, was found in Active Directory"
    }

    # Bind to the computer object using the DirectoryEntry class
    $computerEntry = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://$($computerObject.DistinguishedName)", $credential.UserName, $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)

    # Create a new SecurityIdentifier for the new owner
    $newOwnerSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $newOwnerObject.SID.Value

    # Get the current security descriptor of the computer object
    $securityDescriptor = $computerEntry.ObjectSecurity

    # Set the owner in the security descriptor
    $securityDescriptor.SetOwner($newOwnerSID)

    # Update the computer object with the modified security descriptor
    $computerEntry.CommitChanges()

    Write-Host "Owner of the computer object has been updated to $newOwner."
} catch {
    Write-Host "Failed to update computer object: $_"
}
```

This code works if the computer is already joined to the domain, but does not work if it isn't. As someone who is not proficient with PowerShell, I was hoping for some advice.

Comment: "before joining the computer to the domain", there is no Active Directory record for the computer for anyone to own. Also, computer objects don't have owners at all. Finally, please tell me you didn't name your domain "contoso.com"

Comment: I am pre-creating the computer objects in the OU I need them in and setting descriptions. If you go to Properties > Security > Advanced on the computer object, you will see that there is an owner, which is typically the person who initially made the object.

Comment: That owner is not an active directory attribute. It's part of an ACL.

Comment: The code snippet above correctly changes the owner if the computer I'm running it from is joined to the domain. I just can't get it to work when the computer is not joined to the domain. My question essentially is, how can I do this from a non-domain-joined computer? It successfully connects to AD, it just can't update the owner for some reason.

Comment: And no, I did not name my domain contoso.com, my real domain name is edited out and contoso.com was put in its place to provide the example code.

Comment: Looks like a permissions issue. Since the final commit command doesn't supply any credentials and runs on a computer that's not joined to the domain (so the active user account is also unknown to AD), there's no permissions to set that attribute and as far as I can see no way to get those permissions while running on this machine.

Comment: I assumed it would use the same credentials for the commit as it would to perform the initial connection in:
$computerEntry = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://$($computerObject.DistinguishedName)", $credential.UserName, $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)

Comment: There are several authentication flags when binding to an ADDS object, and it may be that you should try specifying the [authentication flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes) when you [first bind to the object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.-ctor?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). My guess is that you need to specify the Delegation flag to allow out of domain modification.

Comment: I tried changing the line to bind to the object to:
`$computerEntry = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://$($computerObject.DistinguishedName)", $credential.UserName, $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password, [System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes]::Delegation)`

Console output:
Computer object found in Active Directory for [ComputerName]
New owner, [UserName], was found in Active Directory
Computer DN: CN=[ComputerName],OU=Computers,DC=contoso,DC=com
Failed to update computer object: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.